I want to assign numeric values to grid squares from the 50m by 50m fishnet grid I created based on the wind installed capacity in a 20km of a point
I am working in QGIS while writing code in Pycharm. I have to select suitable sites for BESS locations in Germany. Currently I am looking into the state of Saxony-Anhalt. Firstly, I narrowed down on grid connection points that are HV/MV meaning 110kV/30kV, 110kV/20kV, 220kV/110kV etc. Then, I gathered wind data from marktstammdatenregister. I want to calculate how much installed wind capacity is within  20 km radius of each grid connection point. After this I want to show grid connection points for which the wind installed capacity within those radius is under 250MW. I want to generate an initial list of sites that fall under this parameter.
After this I have a grid layer of 50m by 50m. I want to utilize this grid layer by allocating suitable numerical values or "points" to it based on the value of installed capacity around grid connection points. I want that if the installed capacity is more than 250000 kW, then assign the square of the 50m by 50m grid layer inside that 20 km buffer,  -100 to it, and if it is less, then assign 2 to it. Like this I want to generate an entire new shapefile that contains a full list of the grid layer squares and numerical values assigned to each square.
I wrote the code and it generated me the list of the 3 grid connection point sites that have wind capacity under 250 MW in a 20 km radius. But it is not assigning the value of 2 to those grid squares that fall inside that radius. It is assigning -100 to everything. How do I solve this issue?
I also tried to code where I asked it to list the exact squares using the "id" feature in its attribute table which fall under the radius of 20 km for the grid connection point having installed capacity under 250MW. But it still returns with no values for those particular squares.
The code I used:
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd


def assign_values_to_grid(grid_points_path, wind_data_path, grid_layer_path, output_path, radius=20000,
                          capacity_threshold=250000):
    """
    Assign values to 50m by 50m grid squares based on installed wind capacity around grid connection points.

    Parameters:
    grid_points_path (str): Path to the grid connection points GeoPackage.
    wind_data_path (str): Path to the wind capacity data GeoPackage.
    grid_layer_path (str): Path to the 50m by 50m grid GeoJSON.
    output_path (str): Path to save the output shapefile.
    radius (float): Radius within which to calculate the installed capacity (default is 20000 meters).
    capacity_threshold (float): Capacity threshold in kW (default is 250000 kW).
    """
    # Load grid connection points
    grid_points = gpd.read_file(grid_points_path)
    print(f"Loaded {len(grid_points)} grid connection points.")
    print(grid_points.head())

    # Load wind capacity data
    wind_data = gpd.read_file(wind_data_path)
    print(f"Loaded {len(wind_data)} wind capacity data points.")
    print(wind_data.head())

    # Load the 50m by 50m grid layer
    grid_layer = gpd.read_file(grid_layer_path)
    print(f"Loaded {len(grid_layer)} grid squares.")
    print(grid_layer.head())

    # Ensure all GeoDataFrames have the same CRS
    print("Grid Points CRS:", grid_points.crs)
    print("Wind Data CRS:", wind_data.crs)
    print("Grid Layer CRS:", grid_layer.crs)

    grid_points = grid_points.to_crs(wind_data.crs)
    grid_layer = grid_layer.to_crs(wind_data.crs)
    print("CRS aligned for all layers.")

    # Create a 20 km buffer around each grid connection point
    grid_points['buffer'] = grid_points.geometry.apply(lambda x: x.buffer(radius))
    print("Created 20 km buffers around grid connection points.")

    # Verify buffer creation
    print("Sample buffers created:")
    print(grid_points[['Name', 'buffer']].head())

    # Set the active geometry to 'buffer' for spatial join
    buffered_grid_points = grid_points.set_geometry('buffer')

    # Perform spatial join to find wind installations within each buffer using 'predicate'
    wind_data_within_buffer = gpd.sjoin(wind_data, buffered_grid_points, how='inner', predicate='within')
    print(f"Found {len(wind_data_within_buffer)} wind installations within buffers.")

    # Verify spatial join results
    print("Sample results of the spatial join:")
    print(wind_data_within_buffer.head())

    # Calculate the total installed capacity within each buffer using 'InstallierteLeistung' field
    wind_capacity_per_point = wind_data_within_buffer.groupby('index_right')['InstallierteLeistung'].sum().reset_index()
    wind_capacity_per_point.columns = ['grid_point_index', 'total_installed_capacity']
    print("Calculated total installed capacity within each buffer.")

    # Verify capacity calculations
    print("Sample capacity calculations:")
    print(wind_capacity_per_point.head())

    # Merge this information back to the grid points
    grid_points = grid_points.merge(wind_capacity_per_point, left_index=True, right_on='grid_point_index', how='left')
    print(f"Merged installed capacity data with grid points. Resulting grid points: {len(grid_points)}")

    # Filter grid points with total installed capacity below the threshold
    suitable_grid_points = grid_points[grid_points['total_installed_capacity'] < capacity_threshold]
    print(f"Filtered suitable grid points: {len(suitable_grid_points)}")
    print(suitable_grid_points[['Name', 'total_installed_capacity', 'geometry']])

    # Initialize a new column for numerical values in the grid layer
    grid_layer['value'] = -100  # Default value

    # List to store IDs of grid squares assigned the value 2
    squares_with_value_2_ids = []

    # Assign values to grid squares based on installed capacity
    for index, row in grid_layer.iterrows():
        is_within_any_buffer = False
        for buffer_index, buffer_row in suitable_grid_points.iterrows():
            if row.geometry.within(buffer_row['buffer']):
                grid_layer.at[index, 'value'] = 2
                squares_with_value_2_ids.append(row['id'])
                print(f"Grid square {row['id']} assigned value 2 (within buffer of grid point {buffer_row['Name']})")
                is_within_any_buffer = True
                break  # Exit the inner loop if the grid square is completely within a suitable buffer
        if not is_within_any_buffer:
            for buffer_index, buffer_row in grid_points.iterrows():
                if row.geometry.within(buffer_row['buffer']):
                    print(
                        f"Grid square {row['id']} is within buffer of grid point {buffer_row['Name']} but not suitable")
                    break  # Exit the inner loop if the grid square is within any buffer

    # Filter and display the squares assigned the value of 2
    squares_with_value_2 = grid_layer[grid_layer['value'] == 2]
    print(f"Grid squares assigned value 2: {len(squares_with_value_2)}")

    # Display the exact squares with value 2
    if len(squares_with_value_2) > 0:
        print(squares_with_value_2[['id', 'geometry']])

    # Save the modified grid layer to a new shapefile
    grid_layer.to_file(output_path)
    print(f"Saved the modified grid layer to {output_path}")

    return squares_with_value_2_ids


# Example usage
grid_points_path = 'Path to grid connection points shapefile/Example shapefile'
wind_data_path = 'path to wind data shapefile/Example shapefile'
grid_layer_path = 'path to 50m grid shapefile/Example shapefile'
output_path = 'path to output shapefile/Grid with points.shp'
squares_with_value_2_ids = assign_values_to_grid(grid_points_path, wind_data_path, grid_layer_path, output_path)

# Display the results
print("Final list of grid square IDs assigned value 2:")
print(squares_with_value_2_ids)```

